# Need advice assigning XY coordinates with dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am currently building a human predictive model using received signal strength indicator(rssi). I was wondering if its possible to assign the dataset to the XY coordinates and train the model with k nearest neighbour to predict human location thus returning a XY coordinate within the setup? I have been trying to use numpy to create an array of the specific data collected XY coordinates. However as I have collected 10 samples of rssi data of each location, I am in a dilemma on how to proceed with the assigning of the dataset.

If this isn't a feasible method, could anyone point me the right direction to achieve my desired result?

Appreciate any help, please feel free to ask if you require additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe X and Y cordinate will form 2 columns of your dataset which can further be trained using KNN. Have a look at simple example here:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/03/introduction-k-neighbours-algorithm-clustering/

Comment: Did you give it a try?

Comment: hi there, sorry for the late reply, i have gone through your recommendation but that is not what i am looking for, i still appreciate your help though. i am still in the midst of finding the solution.